# Remove some elements of a string and replace with others

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

How can I convert this :

RS.PK.03.01.4200.03.014.01 to man03140101?

What needs to be done?

Text before 5th "." has to be removed : `RS.PK.03.01.4200`.
The remaining text should be converted `03.014.01` should be converted to `031401`.   "0" was removed of "014"
`01` be added to the end: `03140101`
Add man in the front: `man03140101`
I need to do hundreds of such conversions in a file.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/^\([^\.]*\.\)\{5\}\(..\)\..\(..\)\.\(..\)/man\2\3\401/'
```

What it does:

- Five groups of dot-separated non-dots (capturing but ignoring)
- Capturing the other groups
- Rebuild the string